# Using the Mac installer command through java

Tags: java, macos, applet, installation, runtime.exec

I have an applet that I need to be able to launch a .pkg mac installer from my java applet.

Right now I can do so with the following command:

```
Process proc = r.exec(new String[] {"open", "/Volumes/affinegy_homeportal_setup/" + pkg});
```

The problem is, is that this install is to verbose and requires the user to click through the install process which is unlike my windows version of my installer which performs the installer silently in the background. My attempt to achieve this was with this command:

```
Process proc = r.exec(new String[] {"sudo","installer", "-pkg", "/Volumes/affinegy_homeportal_setup/affinegy_homeportal_setup.dmg", "-target", "/"});
```

However when I run this command nothing happens. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Very informative. This helped to reinforce things that I thought I was doing correctly,thanks!

Comment: Yes sir, it gave a more complete understanding of exactly how runtime.exec was working. I ended up creating an applescript file and running that using the mac osascript command through runtime.exec. Thank you very much for that article again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read & implement [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html). And unless you need to support Java 1.4, use a `ProcessBuilder`.